# How to use Storyboard view controllers without reloading each time they show

Tags: ios, swift

I have several UIViewControllers in a Storyboard.
I'm not using a Navigation controller, just simple Segues to show them and to unwind.

However each time show/unwind a View, it completely reloads.

I would like it to "load" only the first time it's shown, and then
hide/show as I move to other View Controllers.

How can this be done using Storyboards and Swift 2?

Comment: Why aren't you using UINavigationController? You know you can hide the navigation bar right? Don't reinvent the wheel

Comment: No particular reason - would using it resolve my issue?

Comment: While unwinding - yes. While showing, no, you will still need to reload them. UINavigationController is basically holding a stack of UIViewControllers - you can push and pop them. I mean you could possibly keep references to the created views and push them on this stack again if they were created before, never tried it though.

Comment: So assume I have a primary VC (VCPrimary) with a button. From VCPrimary I tap But1 and show VC1. VC1 therefore is loaded for the first time. I pop back to VCPrimary. Then I tap But1 again. Is VC1 completely reloaded?

Comment: I'll post an answer on how I would do it

Comment: If I had a text field on VC1 and entered some text, I'd like the text to still be there the next time I tap the button on VCPrimary.

Comment: You should persist the data itself then, not the view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you'd always have a base (menu or something) UIViewController, I'd use UINavigationController and just keep optional references to created UIViewControllers in this menu controller, like :

```
var firstViewController : VC1?
var secondViewController : VC2?
```

You should create a function to get those view controllers like:

```
func getVC1Instance() {
   return firstViewController ?? firstViewController = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("VC1Identifier")
}
```

Then, when you click a button that should take you to VC1 for example, you should do

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(getVC1Instance())
```

I don't know what your use case is, but I really don't recommend retaining UIViewControllers that aren't shown on the screen. If you need to persist their state, just use NSUserDefaults / Singleton pattern to store the data like text typed into some textfields and just use them on viewDidLoad.

Comment: I'm putting together a music player and so far have noticed that when I perform the basic setup of the MediaPlayer in VC1 (to use my previous analogy) and then play a song, if I then unwind to VCPrimary and go back to VC1 the song continues to play as expected, but now the setup for the MediaPlayer has reset. So I'd like to simply pop and push VC1. Does that make more sense?

Comment: It sounds like you should be tracking the state of the media item in some other object; it should not be a direct property of any view controller